# iPhone app, running other code while flipping a view

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog, model-view-controller

In xCode, writing an iPhone app, should I *NOT* put code after/while flipping a view?

I seem to get random crashes....

```
{
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];

    ////////////////// Should I not put any code here???
    // Code that takes 0.0001 secs to run?   Or 0.1 secs?   Or 1-2 secs?
}
```

or when flipping back:

```
{
    [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];   

    ////////////////// Should I not put any code here???
    // Code that takes 0.0001 secs to run?   Or 0.1 secs?   Or 1-2 secs?

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are consirned that the code might effect the graphoc performance of the app, you can use threading. There is a very good guide about that in the documentation. Look it up.

But I think it won't effect the performance. You code will be executed **after** the flipping. Although when it comes to graphich you can never be completely sure.

Answer (score 0):

Like @tadej5553 said your code there will be executed after the flipping is complete. But bare in mind that if you put code that takes 2 seconds to execute then the flip will complete but the UI will be blocked and unresponsive for those 2 seconds. So that should be done in another thread, or at least use a delegate pattern. If you are talking less then 0.1 seconds then it would be ok in my opinion to run it there. Any more and a quick user will notice the lag. If your view can't be used until the operation is complete then I would still do the code in another thread but then just show a `UIAlertView` with a `UISpinner` and no buttons, so the user can't dismiss it. Only when your code is finished will it dismiss the `UIAlertView`